# Vimeo custom play/pause button not working on Ipad

Tags: php, vimeo-api, vimeo-player

I've used vimeo api and created custom play pause button for playing vimeo videos on my site. It's working on every device but not on Ipad. When I click on play button on Ipad it won't do any thing. My code for IOS devices is

```
var vidplaypop = $(this).data('vid');
  var iframeid = document.getElementById(vidplaypop);
  var iframehref = $("#"+vidplaypop).attr('src');

  $('.play-button[data-vid=' + vidplaypop + ']').on("click", function() { 
    var vidplay = $(this).data('vid'); 
    $(this).closest('.vid-top,.frame-video-lrg').find('iframe').attr('id',vidplay); 
    var iframe = document.getElementById(vidplay); 

    // $f == Froogaloop
    $f(iframe).api("play");
    $f(iframe).api("setVolume",1);
});
```

any help would be appreciable.

Thanks
Ali